# Update multiple rows with different values in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I am trying to update multiple rows using an inner view in oracle.

The select statement for updating this view is:

```
select count(distinct a.numCount) as numCount, a.accNum as accNum ,
s.unitNum as unitNum 
from tableA a,tableS s  where a.accNum is not null and s.fk_id=
(select id from tableD where sid=a.accNum ) 
group by a.accNum ,s.unitNum ;
```

Update statement that I am trying is below:

```
update 
(select count(distinct a.numCount) as numCount, a.accNum as accNum ,
s.unitNum as unitNum 
from tableA a,tableS s  where a.accNum is not null and s.fk_id=
(select id from tableD where sid=a.accNum ) 
group by a.accNum ,s.unitNum ) k
set k.unitNum=k.numCount;
```

I am trying to update unitNum with value of numCount.
The above query is not working when used as a view.
Is there another way to update this in Oracle.

Please suggest.

Structure of the tables are as below:

```
TableA

accNum   numCount
-----------------------
111        1
222        5
333        2
111        1
111        1
222        5
222        2


TableS

fk_id  unitNum 
-----------------------
123        0
768        0
734        0

TableD

ID      sid
-----------------------
123      222
768      111
734      333
```

Output should be as below:

```
TableS

fk_id  unitNum 
-----------------------
123        3
768        3
734        1
```

Please suggest

Comment: How the above query is updating ?

Comment: Can you describe more about the tables structure?

Comment: Show us the `update` statement

Comment: updated the update statement in my question .. but that doesn't work ..

Comment: So what is the **exact** error message you get?

Comment: What is the requirement if new rows are added to `TableD`, and now `TableD` has some `ID`'s that are not in `tableS`?  Should the new `ID`'s be added to `tableS`? Also, why is `TableS` a table, and not simply a view?

Comment: the new rows concept will handled by the application .. this query is only for existing rows ..

Answer (score 0):

```
update tableS s
   set unitNum=
        (select count(distinct a.numCount) as numCount
           from tableA a, tableD d
          where s.fk_id=d.id and d.sid=a.accNum
        );
```